# Symfony2 Doctrine indexes with related fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity that has more than 100k records and querys to that table are becoming slower.

It is an entity related to other two, I wonder if it is possible to indexe these two fields, because that all queries are filtered by either of these two field.

I searched google and I have not clarified.

The company is like this:

```
class Ticket
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="tickets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Amce\DemoBundle\Entity\Down")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="related_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $fieldRelated;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Up", inversedBy="tickets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="related2_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $fieldRelated2;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;
```

I want to indexe that fields "fieldRelated" and "fieldRelated2".

Try with this:

```
 *      indexes={
 *          @ORM\Index(name="related_idx", columns={"fieldRelated"})
 *      }
```

But the console throws that error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
>     There is no column with name 'fieldRelated' on table 'Ticket'.

Comment: Replace fieldRelated with related_id

Answer (score 1):

> I want to indexe that fields "fieldRelated" and "fieldRelated2".

```
 *      indexes={
 *          @ORM\Index(name="related_idx", columns={"fieldRelated"})
 *      }
```

You can't explicitly index foreign keys like that because doctrine already does it automatically:

http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/defining-models.html

> Foreign key columns are automatically indexed by Doctrine to ensure
>   optimal performance when issuing queries involving the foreign key.

To figure out how to optimize your query, use symfony's debug toolbar to get the `explain` output of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a property `inversedBy` in $fieldRated:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Amce\DemoBundle\Entity\Down" inversedBy="tickets")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="related_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $fieldRelated;
```

Comment: Nope, this option is not i needed

Comment: Do you have an error when you launch: `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` ?

Comment: Yes, the same as i placed on original post. `There is no column with name 'fieldRelated' on table 'Ticket'.`

Comment: Did you launch: `app/console doctrine:schema:update`?

Comment: Did you add the two relatedField recenly? After creating the Ticket Entity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93238/discussion-between-scoolnico-and-phpprogrammer).